# while using asp.net url routing what is a suggested solution to referencing css files?

Tags: asp.net, css, url-routing

I'm using url routing and I have a stylesheet that is being referenced on the destination page (inside a master page content template):

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <link href="css/actionmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
```

When the page is requested www.mysite.com/mypage it is Ok.  However, if the page is requested as  www.mysite.com/mypage/anotherpage - the reference to the stylesheet breaks.  I tried:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
        <link href="~/css/actionmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server"/>
    </asp:Content>
```

and that didn't help.

My usual solution is to load the stylesheet in codebehind - however, is there another solution I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can use **[Server.ResolveClientUrl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx)** to handle this in ASP.NET:

```
href="<%=Server.ResolveClientUrl("~/css/actionmenu.css")%>"
```

In ASP.NET MVC, you could use the **[Url.Content()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx)** method:

```
href = <%=Url.Content("~/css/actionmenu.css")%>"
```

If you are looking for some additional information on these options, you can check the link below:

**[Different Approaches for Resolving URLs | A Programmer's Blog](http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.com/2009/09/different-approaches-for-resolving-urls.html)**

Comment: maybe petty, but did you have to put it all in bold? Good answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<link href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/actionmenu.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't use an absolute reference - i.e

```
<link href="/css/actionmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```